# Link EGL in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, qt-creator, egl

I have EGL located in my MinGW folder for Qt Creator. What I'd like to know is what the proper linker flag for EGL is. Unfortunately, `-lEGL` and `-legl` do not work.

`LIBS += -legl -lGLESv2 #<-- does not compile`

Is there a workaround for this? Note: I am not looking to use EGL with Qt in regards to the 'Qt way' behind OpenGL. I am merely using Qt Creator for its core framework and such; I plan run an emulator which I downloaded from the [arm website](http://www.malideveloper.com/opengl-es-20-emulator.php) in order to run what I'm doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just found it.

The answer is to prefix `lib` with the ARM based libraries. So,

`LIBS += -llibEGL -llibGLESv2` is the answer, as opposed to `-lEGL` or `-lGLESv2`.